# Typescript Array insert non-duplicate item

Tags: arrays, typescript

We are in 2016, so, I would like to know the best way to insert a non-duplicate item into an array taking into account performance and clean code.

EDIT:

For example:

My object is:

```
obj = {id: 1, a: 2, b: 3, c: 4}
```

My array arr:

```
arr.push(obj);

arr.push(obj); // Avoid this duplicate obj
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to more specific, e.g. what identifies a duplicate item.

Comment: I've updated my question, ok? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native `pushIfUnique` in the language, so you have to options:

(1) If *ordering is not important*  just use a `Map` an the `id` (or whatever) as identifier.

(2) If *ordering is important* you can write a small helper function by using [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). E.g.:

```
const pushIfUnique = (predicate, object, array) => {
  if (!array.find(item => predicate(object, item))) {
    array.push(object);
  }
};
```

Comment: Well, if you only use a property subset to identify an object (= unique because of `id` for example) I guess `Set` will not have any benefits for you, b/c [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) only works with the whole stored value. So you would have to iterate over the entries anyway.

Comment: Ahh, you're amazing! Thank you!